# Elliptic geometry and stereographic projection

Tags: geometry

I was asked this question but I can't find good explanation for that.

> Let $T$ be the transformation from $S$. Prove that $T$ is elliptic and lifts (by stereographic projection) to a rotation of the sphere. 
>   (**hints:** Show that $T$ has two fixed points that are diametrically opposite. Place one of these fixed points at the origin and conclude that $T$ is a rotation.)

I found out that $T$ is:
$$
T(z)=\frac{az+b}{-\bar{b}z+\bar{a}}, \quad \lvert a^2\rvert+\lvert b^2\rvert=1
$$

What should I do to follow the hints???
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

About the hints:

1. Showing the existence of a fixed point should be rather easy: start with $T(z)=z$ and you should obtain a quadratic equation in $z$ which tells you the fixed points.
2. Two points are diametrically opposite on the sphere if they are related by inversion in the unit circle in the plane. You can show this using elementary geometry (think in a cross section of the stereographic projection) and then prove this for the pairs of fixed points you computed before.
3. Requiring one of these to be located at the origin, you can deduce requirements for $a$ and $b$, from which you can then conclude the location of the other fixed point.
4. The hints don't exactly tell you how to generalize from this specific pair of fixed points to arbitrary pairs. How to best achieve this depends a lot on your background, particularly concerning how you define a rotation in 3D.